# Line renderer not plotting both series completely in Rickshawgraph of dashing widget

Tags: javascript, rickshaw, dashing

I am using https://gist.github.com/jwalton/6614023 to render graph for 2 series. When I use data-renderer as scatter-plot or bar, the graph shows both the series properly but if I use line or area, my second series has some data points missing.

My erb file snippet is as follows-

```
<div data-id="convergence" data-view="Rickshawgraph"data-title="Convergence"      
data-min = "95" data-max ="100" data-unstack="true" data-stroke="true" data-  
color-scheme="rainbow" data-renderer ="line"data-legend="true" data-summary-
method="last"></div>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Its likely that its not missing points, but infact overlapping one behind another. From my experience Rickshaw widget by default should not unstack area graphs, but try providing this explicitly

```
data-unstack: false
```